# How to build react component can change view type

Tags: reactjs

I'm working a reactjs project have require to build a component can change view type. Like: the component have "view as icon" and "view as list", and have a button to switching eachother. Which the best way to archive that. Thanks

Edit: Sorry for making confuse
This is exactly what i want. As you can see, i have a mediaComponent and i want it can display in 2 different way: as a list and as thumbnail. So how can i do that with react. I don't actually have code for that.

p/s: I have tried conditional rendering but because it's different in render it's require to re-render the component with forceUpdate(). That's don't really look nice. So i hove there are another solution for that.

[Render as thumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSLxI.jpg)

[Render as list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPtEl.png)

Comment: Please show us some code, this is not a platform get other people to code for you. We want to help but you need to show your own research and time investment first.

Comment: What you need is conditional rendering. Read this, https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html, and instead of `login` props pass your toggle/switch status as props. like if the toggle has boolean state, on `true` render icons, on `false` render list.

Comment: using `setState` forces `render` - no need to use `forceUpdate`, no passing toggle value to items/childs. 'look nice' - if you looking for smooth transition between these views - search for react animation solutions

Answer (score 0):

Something like that perhaps:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isList: false
  }
  toggleList = () => this.setState({ isList: !this.state.isList})

  render(){
    const { isList } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {isList ? <ListComponent /> : <GridComponent />}
        <button onClick={this.toggleList}>Toggle</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```